# How to test a code with Mockito that captures an Exception and returns false

Tags: java, mockito

I know there are several ways to use Mockito in order to test whether a certain exception was thrown. But, my problem is that the method I am trying to test does NOT raise any exception. Rather, my method has a try-catch clause and within the catch clause it simply returns false AFTER capturing an exception. How do I test my method?

```
boolean method() throws DataException {

    try { 
       a.do();
       return true;

    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
      /* Come down here when a is null */
      return false;
    }
}
```

To give it a little more twist, method() is forced to throw DataException since the do() method throws DataException.

So, I have two issues:

1. I must throw DataException from within my test code
2. I must test method() to see whether it captures NullPointerException and returns false.

Editing. Yes, **a** is a mocked object.

Comment: Where does `a` come from in your class?  Is it an injected dependency?

Comment: Mock `a.do();` to throw a DE and an NPE. Assert `method` returns false on NPE, and throws DE on DE.

Comment: @Compass: I would quite appreciate the exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock object `a` and throw a `NullPointerException`

```
@Test
public void itShouldReturnFalse
    when(a.do()).thenThrow(new NullPointerException());

    assertFalse(yourClass.method());
}

@Test(expected = DataException.class)
public void itShouldThrowException() {
    when(a.do()).thenThrow(new DataException());

    yourClass.method();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. I have tried it but it returns true!

Comment: Could you post your test class please?